# How to implement a webkit animation: backgroundmove

Tags: css, animation, background, webkit

I've seen a certain webkit animation type: backgroundmove. It basically just scrolls your background across the page, etc.

I've written a little css blurb for a basic -webkit-backgroundmove animation, but it doesn't work! I've tried everything on IE9/FF4/Chrome (latest). Question: is there something that interferes with the animation, keeping it from starting?  The background shows up, but doesn't scroll linearly, so I'm guessing that there's interference or a problem with -webkit-animation

My css is really basic:

```
div#wrapper.cloud-animation {
    background-image: url(../images/clouds.png);
    background-size: 120%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: -10px 150px;
    -webkit-animation: backgroundmove infinite 50s linear;
}
```

I can't even find documentation online for "webkit backgroundmove" so if anyone knows where to find it, that would be a big help! Thanks -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`backgroundmove` is a custom animation, it doesn't exist, you need to define it yourself.

```
@-webkit-keyframes backgroundmove {
    from {
        background-position: left top;
    }

    to {
        background-position: right top;
    }
}
```

Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/css_animations